# load() content in div and prepend div inside content div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to prepend `div(#loadmore)` inside `div(#boxchatting)` when `div(#boxchatting)` loads the content from `"result.php"`. I used the following code:

```
$('#loadmore').prependTo('#boxchatting');
$('#boxchatting').load('result.php');
```

But it seems it's not working. The content of `"result.php"` is showing, but `div(#loadmore)` disappears. Does anyone have a solution?

Please don't tell me to use `prepend()` to show `result.php`, because I just want to use `load()` to implement `setInterval` refresh data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load()` replaces all content in the target with the response data.

So after you prepend the loadMore, it gets replaced with the new content from `load()`.

Do the prepend in the load completion callback instead:

```
$('#boxchatting').load('result.php', function(){
    $('#loadmore').prependTo(this)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was try your code but still not working, div(#loadmore) still disappear inside div(#boxchatting).

Comment: Inspect the elements in browser dev tools element inspector. Can you see it there? Any css rules that might be affecting it?

Comment: (UPDATE) I was try your following code with some modification placed div element and NOW ITS WORKING! Thank you so much!